# GCM with iOS - error":"MismatchSenderId

Tags: php, ios, google-cloud-messaging

I have an XCode iOS project using google cloud messaging. Utilizing the php from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390180/ios-gcm-push-notifications-not-received-in-background-using-php-sender-and-swift), I am receiving the following error:

> error":"MismatchSenderId

Comment: You are going to have to provide code or more other details about your implementation for us to hope to diagnose this.

Answer (score 0):

`MismatchSenderId` means that the API key that you used to send message doesn't belong to the same project as sender ID that you used on device to obtain registration id.